# buildroot w/W11: error compiling eglibc

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, buildroot

after configuring and running make goes

"make: *** [/home/geekay/devel/buildroot/buildroot-2013.08.1/output/build/eglibc-2.17-svnr22064/.stamp_configured] Error 1"

cat output/build/eglibc-2.17-svnr22064/build/config.log command output

```
<...>

gcc version 4.8.1 (Buildroot 2013.08.1) 

configure:2758: $? = 0

configure:2747: /home/geekay/devel/buildroot/buildroot-2013.08.1/output/host/usr/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi-gcc -V >&5

arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'

arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files

compilation terminated.

configure:2758: $? = 1

configure:2747: /home/geekay/devel/buildroot/buildroot-2013.08.1/output/host/usr/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi-gcc -qversion >&5

arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'

arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2758: $? = 1
configure:2763: checking for suffix of object files

configure:2785: /home/geekay/devel/buildroot/buildroot-2013.08.1/output/host/usr/bin/arm-

buildroot-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c -O2   conftest.c >&5

Assembler messages:

Fatal error: invalid -march= option: `armv7-a'

configure:2789: $? = 1

configure: failed program was:

| /* confdefs.h */

| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Library"

| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "glibc"

| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "(see version.h)"

| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Library (see version.h)"

| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/"

| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/"

| #define PKGVERSION "(Buildroot) "

| #define REPORT_BUGS_TO "<http://www.eglibc.org/issues/>"

| /* end confdefs.h.  */

| 

| int

| main ()

| {

| 

|   ;

|   return 0;

| }

configure:2803: error: in `/home/geekay/devel/buildroot/buildroot-2013.08.1/output/build/eglibc-2.17-svnr22064/build':

configure:2805: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile

<...>
```

what do i need to tune and correct?

Comment: Please send a mail to the buildroot mailing list [1] with your configuration (for example the defconfig file generated with 'make savedefconfig'). There are much more developers there that can help you with this problem...

[1] http://lists.busybox.net/mailman/listinfo/buildroot

Comment: From the log, looks like you're using an external toolchain that doesn't support armv7-a.

Comment: Arnout, come on. The guy is building the eglibc package, so he cannot be using an external toolchain!

Comment: geekay, please post your Buildroot .config file. Without that, there's nothing that can be done to help you.